Install instructions for binaries of packages that needs compilation
I'm writing a package that has Rust code in it. It's not on CRAN yet.
Since my target user won't have Cargo installed (and won't even know what that is) current install instructions points to Releases section where I'm storing precompiled binaries. Workflow is download then install.packages("path/to/download"). That's also no good.
What is the best practice to make binaries available?
I've tried creating a R-Universe repo, which compiles all binaries I need, but install.packages("fio", repos = c("https://albersonmiranda.r-universe.dev", "https://cloud.r-project.org")) downloads source code and not current system's binaries.
I've also considered set instructions to a specific release (i.e. link to binary), but then I'd have to update instructions everytime I bump version, which is not desirable either.

I'd say your 'not desirable' final option of bumping version to specific release is most pragmatic, merely requiring a note to maintainer self. The needs compilation:yes and system reqirements: Rust version >= x should inform the adventuresome of what they need to bring to the party (byo Rust - version x...). Just my thoughts. I know it fails the magic of 'it just worked' and I'm using fio!, but eight years in, perhaps they should have rust version x.
